# android benchmark doesnt show run in log file

Tags: android, adb, tensorflow-lite, nms

I have a few tensorflow models in a tflite format.
When running the commands:

```
adb shell am start -S \
  -n org.tensorflow.lite.benchmark/.BenchmarkModelActivity \
  --es args '"--graph=/data/local/tmp/your_model.tflite \
              --num_threads=4"'
```

and:

```
adb logcat | grep "Average inference"
```

the performance is shown (as expected).

In addition, I have a home-made tflite file of a concrete function of a NMS function (based on tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression).
When I run it using the same command, I don't get any error, but it doesn't show on the log file like the rest of the models for some reason.

Any suggestions why?
P.S
When loading the tflite of the NMS in pc, it works as expected.

Comment: The provided information may not enough to find out the root cause. If the model is converted with the Select TF option, you may need to enable the Select TF enabled benchmark tool.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I solved it @JaesungChung

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
I used the wrong app.
Once I installed the version which supports tf ops, it worked